# From PHP to Python accommodation

Tags: php, python

I've been coding php for years, and now i have to finally make my own project, and i want it very optimized and shiny. So, i've been searching around the net about which programming language should i use for my needs (fast, secure, easy-understandable, customizable) and all points to -> Python. So I decided to go on, but i just can't feel "home" when writing python (inc Django app...). I got used to PHP's syntax, and my IDE (PHP Expert Editor 4.3)  makes php look awesome, so now i just can't go with python.

Maybe there is something which has php's syntax (let's say per example: Perl)...but the advantages of a high-level programming language (aka Python)?

Comment: Syntax is irrelevant compared to semantics, except for boilerplate code (there's none in Python) the most hideous grammars that constantly get in one's way (some claim "the whitespace thing" in Python is this, but 90´5% who use it on a regular basis disagree). It's mostly a matter of getting used to it. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use what you like and what you know. If you want to try something new that's ok .. but if you want to start a serios project now I would not use a new language for this.

Maybe better look what you could do better with php. (Maybe use a better template engine or design clever classes or whatever). Many huge webapps are developed with php and are working very well.

Also I would not say that Django is a highly optimized framework .. if you want to look into something new well documented you could check the flask microframework http://flask.pocoo.org/

Answer (score 2):

This line of work requires you to adjust to different syntaxes (even in PHP alone you need to know sql and js and Css and html too...).
So the answer is no, there is nothing like what you ask, and you better get used to that :-)
b.t.w is Python really faster than PHP?

Answer (score 1):

If you've been coding in PHP for years, then maybe PHP is still the right choice for you? As long as your project is related to web (by the way Facebook uses PHP!) you should stick to it.

Python is really easy and fun to learn, but as any other programming language - it requires time to get into it. And for web projects, you'll have to catch up with frameworks and maybe servers (e.g. tornado).

If you'd like to do something on enterprise level, Java is also a good choice. But never as easy and as fun as Python :)

Comment: I think i will keep coding on PHP. =)